# Tabledata not refreshed with `on_refresh` callback in `on_load` callback

Tags: rubymotion, rubymotion-promotion

My tableview won't reload data , it only shows `noob` but not redreshed data.

Do I missing any steps in my code ?

```
class ReservoirsScreen < PM::TableScreen
  title "I want to refresh"
  refreshable
  def on_load
    @returned_data ||= [{title:'noob'}]
    on_refresh
  end
  def table_data
    [{
      cells: @returned_data.map do |reservoir|
        {
          title: reservoir["title"],
          action: :select_reservoir,
          arguments: { reservoir: reservoir["title"] }
        }
      end
    }]
  end


  def select_reservoir(reservoir)
    PM.logger.info reservoir
  end 


  def on_refresh
    start_refreshing
    get_reserviors
    stop_refreshing
    update_table_data          
  end  

  def get_reserviors
    start_refreshing
    url_string = "http://128.199.223.114:10080/"
    AFMotion::JSON.get(url_string) do |result|
      if result.success?
        @returned_data = []
        result.object["data"].each do |r|
          @returned_data << {
            title: [r["reservoirName"], r["immediatePercentage"]].join(":")
          }
        end
      else
        @returned_data = ['failed','d']
      end
    end 
    stop_refreshing
    update_table_data      
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

AFMotion uses async callbacks, so your code is actually being executed like this:

- start refreshing
- send a request for the JSON
- immediately stop refreshing
- update the table data
- receive the response with the JSON

Instead, move your `stop_refreshing` and `update_table_data` lines into your callbacks (the `if result.success?` / `else` blocks), that way they won't be executed until your JSON response is received:

```
if result.success?
  @returned_data = []
  result.object["data"].each do |r|
    @returned_data << {
      title: [r["reservoirName"], r["immediatePercentage"]].join(":")
    }
  end
  update_table_data
  stop_refreshing
else
  @returned_data = ['failed','d']
  update_table_data
  stop_refreshing
end
```